# Get all words between two characters and replace - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've got the following text:

Maybe you'll get it next time. You can do it <#Name> ! It is now <#TimeOfDay>, and you still need to get <#Target>.

What I need to do is from the text get all the "tags" (<#*TagName*) and replace the tag with some other text such as:

```
<span class="nonEditable" style="cursor: pointer;">&lt;#TimeOfDay&gt; <span onclick="removePlaceholder(this)"/>
    <span class="closeTag">X</span>
</span>
```

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is a template engine, there are many to choose from. EJS, Handlebars, Pug... etc

Comment: I would agree, this looks like a template engine. However the regex on this is simple enough, `/\s?<#([A-Z]\w+)>\s?/g`

Comment: @magreenberg thanks for this, but I don't think that will work. What I actually need to do is something similar to when you mention someone on Facebook. So it needs to be free text, then I should be able to click a button to add a tag and be able to type free text as well.

Comment: @John Do you mean something like [this](http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/). I realize you are not using react, just trying to understand your requirements.

Comment: @magreenberg Yes something like this, but a plugin that allows me to type free text as well, this one only allows predefined data sets

Comment: Do you mean like at any point? I don't know of a plugin for that type of feature, but It wouldn't be to hard to implement. What are you trying to overlay the text on? Is it a photo?

Comment: So the text is read from a service, the tags will be dynamically populated based a user in the DB - so on the web front you capture the free text, and add your tags, and the service reads the text, populates the tags and displays the text with the dynamically populated values on the client

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for something like this. It uses absolutely positioned elements on a relative div.

```js
const field = document.getElementById('field')

function addTag(target, tagText, xPos, yPos){
  const span = document.createElement('span')
  span.innerHTML = tagText
  span.style.position = 'absolute';
  span.style.top = yPos + 'px'
  span.style.left = xPos + 'px'
  target.appendChild(span)
}

addTag(field, 'Hello', 10, 50)
addTag(field, 'SomeTag', 200, 120)
```

```css
#field{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background; #fff;
  border: 5px solid #333;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="field"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with  `regex` (regular expressions).

1.) You need to `create a regex` that matches the criteria of the searched terms

2.) Then execute the `regex.exec()` in a `while loop` to go through all the `matches` since the `regex.exec()` method retrieves only `one match at a time` and remembers the index of the last match. On its next execution `regex.exec()` will start from that index (the `lastIndex`).

3.) replace all occurrences of the match using the `str.replace()` function

---

Here are the basics of what you need to know about regular expressions:

**The RegExp constructor:**

> The RegExp constructor creates a regular expression object for matching text with a pattern.

reference: [https://developer.mozilla.org/RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

**regex.exec():**

> If the match succeeds, the exec() method returns an array and updates properties of the regular expression object. The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was captured.
>   If the match fails, the exec() method returns null (which coerces to false).

reference: [https://developer.mozilla.org/RegExp/exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

**regex flags:**

> The 'g' flag is used with the .exec() method to get iterative progression.
>
> The 'i' flag represents case-insensitive search.

**parentheses '()' inside regex:**

> Parentheses around any part of the regular expression pattern causes that part of the matched substring to be remembered. Once remembered, the substring can be recalled for other use.

reference: [https://developer.mozilla.org/Regular_Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

---

**Below is the code example:**

**Note:** the `function removePlaceholder()` was created as an example to show that the `onclick` methods of the `newly created elements` work.

```js
function removePlaceholder(thisX)
{
   console.log(thisX);                         // print the element
   console.log(thisX.innerHTML);               // print it's contents
   console.log(thisX.children[0].innerHTML);   // print contents of first child element
}


var string = "Maybe you'll get it next time. You can do it <#Name> ! It is now <#TimeOfDay>, and you still need to get <#Target>.";

// this regex will match only letters a-z and A-Z (the 'i' flag) and space characters
// you can add more like 0-9 (all numbers) or \w+ (any alphanumeric character), etc.
// the + sign means one or more characters that are listed inside the bracket []
var regex = new RegExp(/<#([a-z ]+)>/, 'gi');  // Note the parentheses ()

var result;
var changeTo;


while(result = regex.exec(string)) //regex.exec returns NULL when no matches are found
{
   // result[0] -> current match, result[1] -> remembered value from the parentheses
   changeTo = '<span class="nonEditable" style="cursor: pointer;">&lt;#' + result[1] + '&gt; <span onclick="removePlaceholder(this)"/><span class="closeTag">X</span></span>';
   
   string = string.replace(result[0], changeTo); //replace all occurences of the match
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = string; //insert the created html into a div

// console.log(string);    //show the results of the modified string in the console
```

```css
/* CSS just to give the div some borders and padding */
#test
{
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Example div -->
<div id="test"></div>
```